# navier stokes finite element method

Tags: numerical-methods

I have discretized the navier stokes equation in 2D but when I used Newton method to deal with the nonlinear, I don't know the shape of jacobian matrix (you can look at this [finite element for incompressible Navier Stokes equation](http://dspace.uta.edu/bitstream/handle/10106/5144/JIAJAN_uta_2502M_10764.pdf). p28-p30) 
function R is a vector with 15 column and have three part R1 R2 R3 so the Jacobian matrix must be a $15\times15$ matrix but how can you decide where is $\dfrac{\partial R1}{\partial u},\dfrac{\partial R1}{\partial v},\dfrac{\partial R1}{\partial p}$. I mean the dimension of each one will take up in Jacobian matrix

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried AD? [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation).
I do that for implicit method for gas dynamics with Newton and it work fine.